# ElasticSearch Multi-match and scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the following query on Elastic Search 2.3.3

```
es_query = {
            "fields": ["title", "content"],
            "query":
            {
            "multi_match" : {
              "query":      "potato tomato",
              "type":       "best_fields",
              "fields":     [ "title_cuis", "content_cuis" ]
            }
          }
        }
```

I would like the results to be scored so that the first document returned is the one that contains the highest occurrence of the words "tomato" and "potato", but this doesn't seem to happen and I was wondering how I can modify the query to get that without re-indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using best_fields, this will use the max score retrieved in matching process from title_cuis or content_cuis, separately.

Take a look to [cross-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields)